# How to Spark implement the interactive In-Memory Cache?

Tags: scala, jvm, mapreduce, apache-spark

I wonder if a program ends, the memory used for the piece of program are freed by GC.

And how to cache the data in Spark when I am in a interactive scala interpreter?

Is that mean one time of interpreter is in one process?

But much more often, I use terminal to run the code, not in the interpreter itself, in this case, how can I achieve In-Memory?

Answer (score 3):

Either you are working from interpreter or through command prompt, use `rdd.cache()` to use keep rdd in memory.